# "Don't they carry one back to all one's parties?"

Tags: meaning-in-context, british-english, literature

In Katherine Mansfield's *The Garden Party* (1921), there is this question I cannot decipher semantically nor grammatically.

In this scene, this high-society family is preparing a garden party. Cream puffs are delivered, and Laura utters the question in bold in the text below:

> "Godber's has come," announced Sadie, issuing out of the pantry. She
> had seen the man pass the window.
>
> That meant the cream puffs had come. Godber's were famous for their
> cream puffs. Nobody ever thought of making them at home.
>
> "Bring them in and put them on the table, my girl," ordered cook.
>
> Sadie brought them in and went back to the door. Of course Laura and
> Jose were far too grown-up to really care about such things. All the
> same, they couldn't help agreeing that the puffs looked very
> attractive. Very. Cook began arranging them, shaking off the extra
> icing sugar.
>
> **"Don't they carry one back to all one's parties?"** said Laura.
>
> "I suppose they do," said practical Jose, who never liked to be
> carried back. "They look beautifully light and feathery, I must say."

What does it mean to *carry one back* in this context? And *to all one's parties*?

It's also confusing the following play on words, I assume, by Jose. He never likes to be carried back...?

Is this word usage something characteristic of British English, or an archaic expression?

Comment: 'Doesn't seeing them cause memories of all those parties to come flooding back!' Check the closish idiom 'get / be carried away'.

Comment: In 'Don't they carry one back to...', they refers to the puffs ('the puffs carry something/someone back'), 'one' refers to the person, or people, who sees them - someone; so, the puffs take the person who sees them back in time, 'down memory lane', as it were, to the parties that took place in the past (which this person attended). 'Jose' who never liked to carried back' - Jose is someone who does not like to reminisce or dwell in the past.

Comment: FYI, questions like this can also be asked on [literature.se], with the `meaning` tag. If you just want the plain meaning of an English phrase, this site (ELU) is better, but if you want some analysis of the quote in context, Literature would be better.

Comment: @Randal'Thor In this case it was just the meaning of the words, though. Looking back I'm baffled I didn't understand it. I wasn't reading it right. But thanks for the suggestion